# Firebase v9 onSnapShot in async function while being called in useEffect React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase v9, I'm building a chat app, I need to do some async work before calling onSnapShot to get the chat data :

```
      const getChat = async () => {
        // I need to await for user data before doing anything else.
        // I'll need some user data to build the query which
        // I'll be using in onSnapShot later on.
        const user = await getUserData();
        console.log(user);
        
        const collectionRef = collection(db, "messages");
        const q = query(
        collectionRef, where("user_id", "==", user.id), orderBy("createdAt"));
    
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
          const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const entry = doc.data();
    
            return {
              id: doc.id,
              message: entry.message,
            };
          });
          setChatLines(data);
        });
    
        return unsubscribe;
      };
```

Then in useEffect :

```
  useEffect(() => {

    const unsubscribe = getChat();

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

The problem here is that `unsubsribe` is a promise, because `getChat` is async, but I still want to await `getUserData()` before onSnapShot is called, because I'll be needing the user data in the onSnapShot query later.

Is there a way to make this work while being able to `unsubscribe` correctly in useEffect cleanup function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would suggest using a React ref to hold the unsubscribe function to be used in an `useEffect` cleanup function.

```
const unsubscribeRef = React.useRef();

const getChat = async () => {
  const user = await getUserData();
   
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "messages");
  const q = query(
  collectionRef, where("user_id", "==", user.id), orderBy("createdAt"));

  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const entry = doc.data();

      return {
        id: doc.id,
        message: entry.message,
      };
    });
    setChatLines(data);
  });

  unsubscribeRef.current = unsubscribe;
};

useEffect(() => {
  getChat();

  return () => {
    unsubscribeRef.current?.();
  };
}, []);
```

An alternative would be an additional asynchronous function in the `useEffect` hook callback body that can wait for `getChat` Promise to resolve.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe;

  const getChatAndSubscribe = async () => {
    unsubscribe = await getChat();
  }
    
  getChatAndSubscribe();

  return () => {
    unsubscribe?.();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: I used the second approach, but `unsubsribe` is always `undefined` when I console.log it after `getChatAndSubscribe()`, isn't it supposed to be a function?

Comment: @dwix Remember that `getChatAndSubscribe` is declared `async` while the `useEffect` hook callback is completely synchronous. When you are logging `unsubscribe` right after calling `getChatAndSubscribe` it likely hasn't been updated yet. Note that even in the hook cleanup function an Optional Chaining operator is used for the off-hand chance that `unsubscribe` still isn't set by the time the component unmounts.

Comment: I understand. Thank you, I guess that's what it is. In this case is there a way to verify that the clean up is actually working?

Comment: @dwix Check that it's working? I suppose you won't see any React warning about memory leaks, etc... when `setChatLines` is called (*or **not** called because you unsubscribed *). What you *could* do is log `unsubscribe` *in* the `getChatAndSubscribe` function after setting it and you should see that it's a function. You could also add a log or debugger in the cleanup function and check it again there to verify.

Comment: One last question if I may. Why didn't you use a simple variable in the first approach like you did in the second one? I don't understand why you had to use useRef in this case instead of just `let unsubsribe;` and then do as you did in the 2nd approach.

Comment: @dwix The first requires the variable used to hold the unsubscribe function to be in scope of *both* the `useEffect` hook callback *and* the `getChat` declaration. If you used a simple variable in the component it would be reset each render cycle. The React ref allows you to hold on to a mutable variable that persists *through* render cycles. You could OFC just declare the variable *outside* the component, but now *any* "instance" of the component will reference the same variable and this is considered anti-pattern to do in React. (*I shudder at its mention*)

Comment: Ok cool I understand, thanks a ton mate, I appreciate it!